# conditonal distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, beta-function

For conditional distribution 
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

this is the basic definition I know about conditional distribution

> Consider n + m trials having a common probability of success. Suppose,
>   however, that this success probability is not fixed in advance but is
>   chosen from a uniform (0, 1) population. What is the conditional
>   distribution of the success probability given that then + m trials
>   result inn successes?

But for this question

[image]

why for this problem conditional formula looks like

$$f_{X|N}(x|n) = \frac{P(N=n|X=x)f_X(x)}{P(N=n)}$$????

Answer (score 1):

You say you understand
$$f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$$
Then you should also understand
$$f_{Y \mid X} (y \mid x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$
which can be rearranged as
$$f(x,y) = f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x).$$
Plugging this last expression for $f(x,y)$ into the first equation above yields
$$f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) = \frac{f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)}.$$
This is sometimes called Bayes's rule.

Comment: RHS has a typo -- $X|Y$ should be $Y|X$...